# orientation vs position

Tags: nouns

I would like know the difference between position and orientation related to a rotatable object.

On the Internet, I found two terms related to PC monitors: portrait/landscape orientations; and vertical and horizontal positions.  Do these two terms have the same meaning? For example, do two sentences below have the same meaning?

> 1. Place your monitor in vertical and horizontal positions.
> 2. Place your monitor in portrait/landscape orientations.

Comment: In that context, yes, they're the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, position is a broader word.  It can mean both location or angle of rotation, or it can even mean both at the same time.

Orientation is a slightly narrower word, as it can only really mean angle of rotation.

In this context however, and in these two sentences, both words have the exact same meaning: angle of rotation.  As such, both sentences convey the same information, identically, without any real difference.  The choice between the two words is purely habit or personal preference.